# HLS Player: Clear video.js buffer on click

Tags: html5-video, http-live-streaming, video.js

I have two live videos feeding an encoder which creates H.264 chunk files and an HLS manifest which is being served by an apache web server.

A browser page using [video.js](https://videojs.com/) shows a player. Pressing "play" on the browser properly plays the video. It works well.

However, if we change video sources (by flipping the switch in the picture below), there is a considerable delay (10 seconds) before the new content is displayed in the player.  I'd like to get that to 3 seconds.

It appears that `video.js` and/or the HTML5 player in browser is buffering that amount of content. (if you delete the files on the web server, kill apache, or even pull the ethernet cable, the video keeps on playing!)

A button on the web page controls the switch. When clicked, I would also like to clear or reset the player so that it immediately re-reads the `index.m3u8` manifest and downloads the new chunks.

So far, haven't found anything promising searching the internet or in the video.js API docs.  There are lots of articles on API calls for fetching the current buffer percentage but cannot find any API for clearing it altogether.

Any ideas?

The encoder is set for 3 second chunks and the playlist depth is set for 10 entries.

[image: video switcher connected to HLS encoder]

Comment: Hello, Have you solved this problem? I also come cross a problem like you

Comment: Hi.  No I could never solve it.  I worked on it a long time but finally gave up on HLS and moved to MPEG-DASH using the dash.js player from the MPEG-DASH forum.  MPEG-DASH is more difficult to understand but it seems to have better operation in low-latency.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Since i could not find a reliable API for this, i came up with a rather dirty workaround to clear the buffer:

```js
var ctime = player.currentTime();
player.currentTime(0);
player.currentTime(ctime);
```

This currently works for me in all major browsers.